# How to arrange images by their dominant color?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, color-theory

I want to arrange a stack of images by their primary color/s - or another, aesthetic way by involving an algorithm, *rather than my own poor judgement.* Is there a tool for doing so?

[image: images with different dominant colors]
<sub><sup>These are Photoshop CS4 layers, so a plugin solution would be great, but anything is appreciated :)</sup></sub>

Comment: With little coding you can sort them by [saturation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124745/algorithm-for-sorting-images-by-relevance) or by [hue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841510/sorting-items-by-their-color). See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014402/sorting-a-list-of-colors-in-one-dimension), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323/followup-sorting-colors-by-distinctiveness) and [here](http://www.w7forums.com/threads/sorting-pictures-by-color.11683/).

Comment: Google "Sort images by color" --- there's a few apps. No idea if any are good. Downvoting for lack of effort.

Comment: @PaoloGibellini Fascinating material, thank you!